# How I get to know that i back from other app in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Actually i am opening other app from my app and than after when i come back to my app using top left button.

So here i want to know is there any way to identify that i came back from other app so i will put condition on it.

After back to my app there is two method of appDelegate is called.

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
```

But I want any particular condition to put here to get to know about it.

As many down vote this question. I want to add as when i back from other app my app goes black.

So for this reason i want to check it and if it's from other app i will assign view again to controller.

Thank you in advance.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if someCondition {
        print("Coming back from another application")
    } else {
        print("Coming back from app switcher/home")
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to know from which app user has come back?

Comment: @KeshuR. He wants to know whether the app is coming back from another app or not

Comment: @iOSDev yes, right.

Comment: **But I want any particular condition to put here to get to know about it.** . print,alert,notifications etc. you can use anything,

Comment: @KeshuR. You didn't understand the question. `if someCondition { print("Coming back from another app") } else { print("Coming back from app switcher/home") }` What condition can be used to find this?

Comment: @iOSDev right you understand my requirement.

Comment: then declare a global bool variable, something like `var openingAnotherApp = false` .. Now when you open another app, before opening it, make your `openingAnotherApp = true` . Now in your AppDelegate, you can check if `openingAnotherApp` is true or false. And then again change it value back to false after your condition check completes. Make sense?

Comment: @KeshuR. No. Even if he declares a variable, the user can use app switcher and go to any other app. `1. App A -> App B -> App A`  `2. App A -> App B -> App C/Home -> App A`

Comment: @iOSDev. I want mention here that this issue only occurs while open other app if i move app in background and than open it. There is no issue.

Comment: @KeshuR. your idea with create bool var and set true while open other app and check for it while back is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Just adding the comment as answer:***

Declare a global bool variable, something like `var openingAnotherApp = false`

Now when you open another app, before opening it, make your `openingAnotherApp = true` .

Now in your `AppDelegate`, you can check if `openingAnotherApp` is `true` or `false`. And then again change it value back to `false` after your condition check completes.